# how to correctly display a large datalist on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, input, html-datalist

I recently made a form that requires an input that needed an autofill. Everything was working fine until I tested it with a large amount of data, where it suddenly break.

I used a datalist where the options are set dynamically, and if everything works fine on edge or firefox, the input's dropdown is not lined up properly when used with chrome.

**Here's on firefox and edge respectively:**

[image: snippet for firefox]

[image: snipet for edge]

**And now , here's what it looks like on chrome**

[image: snippet for chrome]

I tried several things, such as populating it asynchronously, but nothing seems to do the trick, no matter the way I code it, as soon as the list length is beyond a certain point doesn't line with its input anymore. Any help would be greatly appreciated

**exemple**

HTML

```js
let el = document.getElementById('exemple');
        for(i=0;i<200;i++){
            let option = document.createElement('OPTION');
            option.innerHTML = i
            el.appendChild(option);
        }
```

```html
<input list="exemple">
<datalist id="exemple">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Add a snippet demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @connexo it's done.

Comment: Works exactly as you wished it would for me in latest Chrome/Win.

Comment: @connexo the suggestion box lines up properly ? Maybe it's just my version, i'll try with my collegues computer then.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Select2 library for your datalist (https://select2.org/dropdown)

Comment: I'll look into it :)